# How to show and change multiple images in a frame in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to show multiple images in a frame and when user click the image will change but when I am doing this all the images are showing one after another in a verticle line.

I am doing this:

```
             <div class="container-fluid">
              <div class="row" style="width:280px;height:360px">

                <?php $photos = explode(',',$product['image']);
                 foreach($photos as $photo):
                   ?>
                   <?php /*<img src="<?= $product['image']; ?>" alt="<?= $product['title']; ?>" class="img-thumb-detailModal"> */?>
                   <img src="<?= $photo; ?>" alt="<?= $product['title']; ?>" class="img-thumb-detailModal">

                <?php endforeach;?>
              </div>
            </div>
```

The result what I am getting is below:
[image: Here is the problem. My frame is style="width:280px;height:360px"]

I want all the images will show in style="width:280px;height:360px" frame and with next and previous<> buttons so that when users click on the image the image gets change. I have used fotorama but it changes my CSS and my client also suggest to build it in jQUERY and not to use fotorama in their project.

Your valuable suggestions would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should set the appropriate CSS rules:

```
img {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
}

.active-image {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

You should add the 'active-image' to the first image, then through javascript assign the 'active-image' class to the next image when clicked.

Check this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cmrfdb2a/43/) as an example.

Comment: not getting.  Apologize but it too complicated for me at the moment.

Comment: I have done it exactly the same what you guided me but when I pressed the button all the images have gone.

Comment: Your PHP seems fine. You are probably writing something wrong in your JS.

Comment: In your example JSFiddle, there is no Next and Previous button. If they are changing then I can get some hints how they work and can implement it in my code.

Comment: In my example the image change when you click on it.

Answer (score 0):

HTML CODE:

```js
var slideIndex = 0;
var t;
// Next/previous controls
function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides1_1(slideIndex += n);
}

// Thumbnail image controls
function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides1_1(slideIndex = n);
}
// - FUNZIONE SLIDESHOW
function showSlides1_1(n) {
 var i;
 var slides = $(".mySlides");
 var dots = $(".dot");
 if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1} 
 if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
 for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
   slides[i].style.display = "none"; 
 }
 for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
   dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
 }
 slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block"; 
 dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
 $(slides[slideIndex-1]).css({"backgroundImage" : "url('imagePatch/'" + slideIndex + ".jpg)", "background-repeat" : "no-repeat", "background-size" : "100%", "background-position" : "center center"});
}
```

```css
div.slideshow-container {
 height: 100%;
 position: relative;
 margin: auto;
}
/* Hide the images by default */
.mySlides {
    display: none;
 text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
 -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 0 80px 50px #c4b4b4;
box-shadow:inset 0 0 80px 50px #c4b4b4;

}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slideshow-container">
   <div class="mySlides fade"><!--IMG1--></div>
   <div class="mySlides fade"><!--IMG2--></div>
    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
  </div>
```

Paste the images into a folder and rename them with numbers, e.g .: 1.jpg, 2.jpg.
JavaScript ricevendo come input l'indice del bottone e inserirà ogni foto con la proprietà background-image.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

PHP:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row stackGallery">

    <?php
      $photos = explode(',',$product['image']);
      foreach($photos as $photo):
    ?>

      <img class="img-thumb-detailModal stackButton" src="<?= $photo; ?>" alt="<?= $product['title']; ?>">

    <?php endforeach;?>

      <a class="stackButton sx" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</a>
      <a class="stackButton dx" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</a>

  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.stackGallery {
  padding: 20px;
  width: 280px;
  position: relative;
}
.stackSlides {
  display: none;
}
.stackButton {
  font-size: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 180px;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.sx {
  left: 2px;
}
.dx {
  right: 2px;
}
```

JS:

```
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("stackSlides");
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     x[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
}
```

Check this [pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RYZYyo) to see it in action

Comment: Thanks! I have tried your code its working fine when there is no php involve like codepen. But When I add above code with php the previous and next button not working only image is showing with next and previous button.

Comment: @Sarah how did you integrate the js/css code (with a script/style tag or in an external file)?